# How to create a full width background video(Vimeo)? in Bootstrap environment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a solution/tutorial for full width videos without borders?

I took a look at an existing solution:
[Full-width vimeo wrapper background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314206/full-width-vimeo-wrapper-background)

I tried it but I'm getting unwanted (black) borders when I scale to different viewport sizes.

```
 <div class="video">    

 <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/120893740?title=0&     amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=3a6774&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1" width="960" height="600" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> 
 <div
 class="overlay">
   <h1>HEADING HERE</h1>
   <p>Content Here</p>

 </div> 

 </div>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1, p {
     text-align: center
}
.video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%}

    .video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }

.video .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want video to fill the entire page? or you just want the size to stay the same but without black boxes??

Comment: Maybe make your background in .overlay completely transparent?